# Maintainable data with multilingual content

Tags: kentico

I require to create a storage for employee info, maybe 1000~2000 employees.
And the employee info will be shown on the website.

Besides, I also need the division(10~20) and position(50~200) info to be maintainable.

So when I input the employee info for division and position, it could be select from a drop down list or any selector that could work.

But the name of the division and position are multilingual content.

Can anyone propose me a suitable way to structure these info storage?

Here is my current plan:

1. Employee : Custom Modules
2. Division : Custom Table
3. Position : Custom Table

To achieve multilingual content, I use the concept by keeping the localization string key for division name and position name. E.g. {$ AssistantSecretary $}

But when I input employee info, from the selector already translate based on the default culture setting. End up my default culture is UK, so I can only get division name and position name in English.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you putting all of this into custom tables?

You could consider modeling the employees as content (page type) and the division and position as taxonomy (through categories).

By making your employee content you get full multilingual support. The category names can be managed using localization (which is accessible to editors in Kentico 10 but not in earlier versions).

Note that translation with localization will use the current user language unless you explicitly specify the language.

For example: `ResHelper.LocalizeString(divisionName, "de-de")` would return the German translation, if available, regardless of the current user preferred language.

Comment: Do you mean putting the LocalizeStringKey in Categories application > Display name field?

Comment: Don't input it directly. That field uses the localizable text box control. When you enable multiple cultures on the site, you can hit the + in the field to select the appropriate string resource. Note that you can use that control on your own classes and page types as well.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a specialist for localizing content in Kentico but I like more SoYuJe`s original way of storing data in custom tables.

There are some difficulties with Marnix`s approach - you are right there is out-of-the-box localization functionality while modeling content (employees in this example), but original requirement requires up to 2000 employees - there are some [limitations](https://docs.kentico.com/k9/developing-websites/defining-website-content-structure) which could cause problems you should consider before implementing.

> We recommend that each item (page) in the content tree have at most 1000 direct child pages. This is something we recommend taking into consideration from the very beginning of your development process.

Comment: I can tell from first hand experience that it's not quite as dramatic as the recommendation states. We've recently delivered a Kentico 9 MVC site with 11.000 pages under a single node (also employees) and did not see any performance problems.

Comment: Marnix, the limit is more for the Admin UI instead of the front end display. Also, MVC front end display makes if faster for the front as well.

Comment: Martin, in there case, they can create some sub directories for the employees like A-Z or based on division, etc.

Comment: Yes, you are definitely right. I just wanted to point there are some restrictions to be considered before the decision.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ResHelper.GetString(divisionName) and as you switch languages on the website the returning string will be of the current language. Localization will have options of translation for each language installed to the website/instance.